# Olympus Pen EES-2: Can the ASA move?

Tags: film, troubleshooting, shutter-speed, iso, olympus

I have recently acquired an Olympus Pen EES-2 from my grandmother. I am new to photography in general and would like to ask about the camera itself.

Attached here is the sample photo of the EES-2 from a site and I would like to ask if the ASA can be moved? Because mine is currently stuck at 250. Everything else like the apertures and focus distance works.

[image: Should the ASA move?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this photo, turning the front silver ring is the only way to set it.
[image: https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3465/3386070792_b05403a22a.jpg]